# Laravel 5 Eloquent relation "Has Many Through" SQL Exception

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, relation

*Hello. Yesterday I spend more than 6 hours to understand how the ORM relations working in laravel 5.* But I am not very familiar with them yet.

After hundred errors, test, researches, etc... I made a part of my relations to work correctly.

---

### Relations between the models:

```
/* User.php (Model) */
public function lists() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\ListModel');
}
public function tasks() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Task', 'App\ListModel',
                                             'user_id', 'list_id');
}

/* ListModel.php */
protected $table = 'lists';

public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('\App\User', 'list_id');
}
public function tasks() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Task', 'list_id');
}

/* Task.php (Model) */
public function listModel() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\ListModel', 'list_id');
}
```

---

### What working in an controller:

```
/* Returning all tasks (I have only one user yet. All tasks belongs to him) */
$request->user()->tasks()->get();

/* Working - Returning the list | lists */
$list = $request->user()->lists()->where('id', 'some-id')->first();
$lists = $request->user()->lists()->get();
```

### Where the exception occurs

```
/* Next line throws the SQL Exception */
$task = $request->user()->tasks()->where('id', '5')->first();
```

---

**The exception**:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]:
Integrity constraint violation: 1052
Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous 
(SQL: select `tasks`.*, `lists`.`user_id` from `tasks`
inner join `lists` on `lists`.`id` = `tasks`.`list_id` where 
`tasks`.`deleted_at` is null and `lists`.`deleted_at` is null
and `lists`.`user_id` = 1 and `id` = 5 limit 1)
/* The problem in where clause ^^^^^^^ */
```

---

The SQL query generated by laravel is not working. I think the table of `id` must be defined.

**Note**: The **`ListModel`** class uses **`protected $table = 'lists'`**. the **`List` word is native** in PHP **(T_LIST)**. This table name change made my days sick. Laravel's documentation about "ORM custom keys" is somehow small.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem actually was is in the `QueryBuilder`.

`$request->user()->tasks()` Returns `QueryBuilder`
I am not sure how exactly it works. But I think the `where()` function adds additional SQL.

### **Solution**:

I changed this line:

```
$task = $request->user()->tasks()->where('id', '5')->first();
```

To:

```
$task = $request->user()->tasks()->where('tasks.id', '5')->first();
```

Where `tasks` is the table in the DB and `id` is the column.

Comment: It's too late now, but you can also use `find()` if you know the `id` of your record.